# Hep needed with WordPress Directory theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this Directory theme:

http://themeforest.net/item/directory-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/10480929

Just go to the first preview. So that you can see the categories below the map. I have set that in a different style but it is showing me alphabetically. Here is the code used for that:

```
                        'posts_per_page'            => "-1",
                        'post_type'                 => 'directory_types',
                        'post_status'               => 'publish',
                        'orderby'                   => 'ID',
                        'order'                     => 'ASC',
```

Can you please help me how to adjust the code so that they are not arranged in alphabetical order and by the order I wanted?

Here is the link for reference:

test.techkalph.com

Note: No post/category reorder plugin is working there. Need to adjust the code.

Comment: How do you want to sort them?

Comment: I need to sort them as my order. That means the Others should be at very last. IT should be at first like this. If that can be sorted by date, then also it is fine.  I will add the posts again with my serial so that will will remain as my choice.

Comment: A, B or C? Oh wait...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is part of a get_posts() call. There are at least three ways to do this, depending on how much functionality you have with the properties of the directory types.

**Option 1**. If you can set the "order" of the directory type (it will be an option somewhere when you edit the directory type), then you can make them list in that order by changing the following:

```
'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
```

**Option 2**. If you don't have the ability to set the order, it gets a little more cumbersome. You will first need to get the post IDs of the directory types (when you edit them, it will probably say something like "post=13" in the URL). You can then set the order by changing the following:

```
'orderby'     => 'post__in',
'include'     => '43,12,21,45',
```

Where the numbers after 'include' is the order that you want. Note that this requires you to list *all* the directory type ids that you want listed.

**Option 3** If you can't do either of the above, you can order them by date by setting the following:

```
'orderby'    => 'date',
'order'      => 'ASC',
```

If they are in the reverse order of what you were thinking, try 'order' => 'DESC' instead.

If you can change the publish date of the posts, this will work.

Also, see [Template Tags/get posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). There may be something more tricky that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Hello Dan,  

Thank you for  your reply but unfortunately both will not work for me.

1. There is no such instance in that file so that I can adjust that.

2. The page do not generate any ID there. Here is a sample URL you can check:

http://test.techkalph.com/listing-plain-heading/?filter=all&type=insurance&submit=

Can you please mention how to adjust the above code so that it will show by date so that I can add them again with my serial so that they will be there as per my requirement?

Thank you.

Comment: I added an Option 3 if you want to order by date. Note that 'order' => 'DESC' will reverse the order if its wrong the first time. Let me know if this works.